# How to count a matching pattern in one line?

Tags: shell, design-patterns, awk, count, grep

`enter code here`I have a fasta file containing sequences

```
>lcl|QCYY01003067.1_cds_ROT65593.1_2 
ATGCGTCTCCCCTTTAGAGAGTTCTCTCTAGCTACGTA
>lcl|QCYY01003067.1_cds_ROT65593.1_3
ATCTCTNNNNNNNNNNATATCCCCTTTNNNNNCTCTCT
>lcl|QCYY01003067.1_cds_ROT65593.1_4
ATCTCTNNNNNNNNNNATATCCCCTTCTCGGGGCCCC
```

I wanted to count the number of 'N' and also the number of patterns occurring in each line. No need to include header (>lcl|QCYY01003067.1_cds_ROT65593.1_2 )

eg:-

```
 line 2=0,0
 line 4=15,2
 line 6=10,1
```

How to improve this code:

```
grep -n '[{N}]' <filename> | cut -d : -f 1 | uniq -c
```

Comment: What is 'number of patterns'?

Comment: In the second line, the pattern of the occurrence of 'N' can be seen at two positions. I wanted to count that pattern (ATCTCT "NNNNNNNNNN" ATATCCCCTTT "NNNNN" CTCTCT)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
!/^>/{
  while(match($0,/N+/)){
    count++
    total+=length(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH))
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
  printf("%s %d=%d,%d\n","line",FNR,total,count)
  count=total=""
}
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
line 2=0,0
line 4=15,2
line 6=10,1
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code here.

```
awk '                                                                 ##Starting awk program from here.
!/^>/{                                                                ##Checking condition if a line is NOT starting from > then do following.
  while(match($0,/N+/)){                                              ##Running a while loop which will run till a match found for N characters continuous occurrence.
    count++                                                           ##Doing increment to variable count with 1 each time cursor comes here.
    total+=length(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH))                          ##Creating total variable which is keep adding its own value along with length of matched regex, where regex is looking for continuous occurrence of N character in current line.
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)                                      ##Resetting value of current line to have only REST of line which starts from very next character of matched regex. So that we can skip previous matched regex and look for others in rest of the line.
  }                                                                   ##Closing BLOCK for above mentioned while loop here.
  printf("%s %d=%d,%d\n","line",FNR,total,count)      ##Printing values line,FNR,total,count variables here.
  count=total=""                                                      ##Nullifying variables count and total here, so that previous values should NOT be added to current values of it.
}
'  Input_file                                                         ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Input has only 3 lines. How did you get line 4, line 6??

Comment: @Guru, I believe OP didn't place code tags that is the reason of it is not clear, lemme fix OP's post now.

Comment: @Guru, I have fixed OP's sample now, kindly do lemme know in case of any queries here.

Comment: If I want the output as per sequence, not per line by line (>lcl|QCYY01003067.1_cds_ROT65593.1_2 
ATGCGTCTCCCCTTTAGAGAGTTCTCTCTAGCTACGTA= Sequence 1), How will modify this code?

Comment: @NimishaBalan, IMHO, if you could open a new thread for same, since answers are there and changing original question may impact future users, I would like to request you to open a new question and we will discuss there, cheers and Happy new year :)

Answer (score 7):

Another awk:

```
$ awk 'NR%2==0{printf "line %d=%d,%d\n",NR,gsub(/N/,"N"),gsub(/N+/,"")}' file
```

Output:

```
line 2=0,0
line 4=15,2
line 6=10,1
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
NR%2==0 {                                                      # process even records
    printf "line %d=%d,%d\n",NR,gsub(/N/,"N"),gsub(/N+/,"")    # count with gsub
}' file
```

`gsub(/N/,"N")` counts the amount of `N`s in the record (returns the amount of replacements). `gsub(/N+/,"")` counts the number of consecutive strings of `N`s. Notice, that `""` removes those `N`s from the record so if you need to later further process the data, use `gsub(/N+/,"&")` instead.

**Updated:**

The version I wrote for [your already-deleted next question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59574821/how-to-count-the-frequency-of-letter-in-a-sequence-file).

I added an extra line to your data which demonstrates the question I asked in the comments (is `...N\nNN..` one (`NNN`) or two (`N`,`NN`) *patterns* of your definition):

```
...
>seq4
ATCTCTNNNNNNNNNNATATCCCCTTCTCGGGGCCNNN
NNNNNTTTTTCTCTCTCGCGCTCGTCGAAAAATGCCCC
```

This one is for GNU awk (for using `RT`):

```
$ gawk '
BEGIN {
    RS=">seq[^\n]+"
}
NR>1 {
    # gsub(/\n/,"")  # UNCOMMENT THIS IF NEWLINE SEPARATED PATTERN IS ONE PATTERN 
    printf "%s=%d,%d\n",rt,gsub(/N/,"N"),gsub(/N+/,"")
}
{
    rt=RT
}' file
```

Output (pay special attention to the `seq4`):

```
>seq1=0,0
>seq2=15,2
>seq3=15,2
>seq4=18,3
```

or if you uncomment the `gsub(/\n/,"")` to remove the newline separating strings, the output is:

```
>seq1=0,0
>seq2=15,2
>seq3=15,2
>seq4=18,2
```

One-liner (with the one `gsub` uncommented):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=">seq[^\n]+"}NR>1{gsub(/\n/,"");printf "%s=%d,%d\n",rt,gsub(/N/,"N"),gsub(/N+/,"")}{rt=RT}' file
```

Comment: Updated the version from the other question as part of this answer.